# Cannot properly calculate loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm currently completing an assignment for a simple ticketing system, and I am stumped as to how the loop is not properly calculating.

Basically, the program is to calculate the total cost of a ticket purchase at a local cinema, however, as the user inputs a particular ticketType and quantity, the loop is meant to reset, the user inputs a second ticketType and quantity, and this process is to be repeated any number of times until the user cuts the loop, and the total calculated cost for all loops is presented.

I've had some assistance here and in person with my code, and I am stumped as to why this loop is not properly looping! A single loop is calculated perfectly however a second loop is failing.

I have currently tried using an enumerated class which has assisted with other issues around ticket calculations.

```
package ticketingsystem

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class ticketingsystem {

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String order, again;
    int quantity = 0;
    double totalPrice;
        totalPrice = 0;
    TicketType ticketType;

    System.out.println("  ");

    System.out.println("Welcome to the cinemas!");

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("The cinema has the following options");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("1 = Child (4-5 yrs)");
    System.out.println("2 = Adult (18+ yrs)");
    System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ yrs)");

    do {
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.print("Enter your option: ");
      order = br.readLine();

      switch (order.toLowerCase()) {
        case "1":
          ticketType = TicketType.child;
          break;

        case "3":
          ticketType = TicketType.senior;
          break;

        default:
          ticketType = TicketType.adult;
          break;
      }

      System.out.print("Enter the number of tickets: ");
      quantity = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

      totalPrice += ticketType.getPrice() * quantity;
      System.out.printf("You are purchasing %s tickets at %.2f \n", ticketType, ticketType.getPrice());

      System.out.print("Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : ");
      again = br.readLine(); 
    }
    while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.printf("Total Price           : $%.2f \n", totalPrice);
  }
}
```

I have linked the ticketing prices to an enum class as well, details as follows:

```
package ticketingsystem;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
enum TicketType {
    child(18), adult(36), senior(32.5);

    TicketType(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    private double price;

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

The expected output is the loop to be repeated an infinite number of times, while retaining the previous calculated figures for as long as the user desires.

There is no error message, however the system has no output after inputting tickettype and quantity during the second loop.

Comment: In your loop quantity is always newly set. totalPrice is accumulated over the loop. Is that correct?

Comment: does your program compile ? you don't have error `totalPrice` might not have been initialized ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Yes there is the totalprice error but it still compiles and runs... Do you think there is an issue here I have not seen yet?

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? If it is an error, then you will be running an old version of the code (because this version did not compile). If it is just a warning, then it should initialise to 0.0 by default.  Try doing a *clean and build* in your IDE- to be sure.

Comment: it is an error, please rebuild your project

Comment: hmm no, it seems to just be a warning when reset IDE.. no error message and problem persists

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have also used the ticketprices with an enum class (I have edited my question along with some debugging suggestions from IDE completed just now).

Comment: I have used all of your code exactly and the program runs fine. If you want to run it infinitely why not hardcode the inputs?

Comment: Enum constants should be in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried with the following codes, everything is working well.

```
package mm.com.java.so.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TicketingSystem {

    enum TicketType {

        CHILD(18), ADULT(36), SENIOR(32.5);

        TicketType(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        private double price;

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String type, again;
        int quantity = 0;
        double totalPrice = 0;
        TicketType ticketType;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the cinemas!\n");

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU\n");
        System.out.println("The cinema has the following options\n");
        System.out.println("1 = Child (4-5 yrs)");
        System.out.println("2 = Adult (18+ yrs)");
        System.out.println("3 = Senior (60+ yrs)");

        do {

            System.out.print("\nEnter your option: ");

            type = br.readLine();

            switch (type) {
                case "1":
                    ticketType = TicketType.CHILD;
                    break;

                case "2":
                    ticketType = TicketType.ADULT;
                    break;

                default:
                    ticketType = TicketType.SENIOR;
                    break;
            }

            System.out.print("Enter the number of tickets: ");

            quantity = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            totalPrice += ticketType.getPrice() * quantity;

            System.out.printf("--> You are purchasing %s - %s Ticket(s) at $%s\n", quantity, ticketType, ticketType.getPrice());

            System.out.print("\nDo you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : ");

            again = br.readLine();

        } while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        System.out.printf("\n==> Total Price : $%s \n", totalPrice);
    }
}
```

You can check my test result here.

```
Welcome to the cinemas!

MAIN MENU

The cinema has the following options

1 = Child (4-5 yrs)
2 = Adult (18+ yrs)
3 = Senior (60+ yrs)

Enter your option: 1
Enter the number of tickets: 1
--> You are purchasing 1 - CHILD Ticket(s) at $18.0

Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : y

Enter your option: 2
Enter the number of tickets: 2
--> You are purchasing 2 - ADULT Ticket(s) at $36.0

Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : y

Enter your option: 3
Enter the number of tickets: 3
--> You are purchasing 3 - SENIOR Ticket(s) at $32.5

Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : n

==> Total Price : $187.5
```

> NOTE :: If you are JAVA developer, you have to follow JAVA Rules and Regulation when you are coding(e.g Class Name). I formatted your code. pleae check carefully.

This code worked with no error in my PC.

Comment: Ah excellent thank you so much!! Yes it works perfectly! I was stumped on this for so long! The problem I had was not using upper case in the enum class.

Comment: So, accept the answer and vote up. Not forget, your are in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I also just tried the code from your original posted question.

The *only thing* wrong with the code in your question was a missing semi-colon from the package statement in the `public class ticketingsystem` main class.

This is an error, which meant that when you compiled, it would have failed and simply ran a previous version of the code. That is probably why you did not get the result you expected (you were running an old version).

Here is a transcript of my session using your exact code (plus a semi-colon on the package statement of the main class):

```
Welcome to the cinemas!

MAIN MENU

The cinema has the following options

1 = Child (4-5 yrs)
2 = Adult (18+ yrs)
3 = Senior (60+ yrs)

Enter your option: 1
Enter the number of tickets: 2
You are purchasing child tickets at 18.00 
Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : y

Enter your option: 2
Enter the number of tickets: 3
You are purchasing adult tickets at 36.00 
Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : n

Total Price           : $144.00
```

Expensive cinema!

FWIW, as R. Katnaan said, you must follow the syntax rules. However capitalisation of enum element names is not a rule of the language. It is a highly advocated convention (coding standard). I agree you should use Capitals for your enum elements, but that is not what broke the code as per your question...

If you follow that coding convention, you should also use Capital CamelCase for class (interface and enum names) and others. For example, use `public class TicketingSystem` and not `public class ticketingsystem`. Following are a couple of guides for naming conventions. Remember, these are guides not rules enforced by the compiler:

- [DZOne - Best Practices for Variable and Method Naming](https://dzone.com/articles/best-practices-variable-and)
- [Oracle - Naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
- [Geeks for Geeks - Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)

The conventions are important as they give the reader of your code some clues as to what they might be looking at. For example if I see `x = SOME_VALUE;` I will assume x is being assigned a constant as opposed to `x = someValue;` I will assume x is being assigned the value from another variable. And so on...

Answer (score 1):

I didnt seem to find any issue in your code when I run it. please see the below output when i run your code,  it is calculating perfectly:

```
Welcome to the cinemas!

MAIN MENU

The cinema has the following options

1 = Child (4-5 yrs)
2 = Adult (18+ yrs)
3 = Senior (60+ yrs)

Enter your option: 2
Enter the number of tickets: 2
You are purchasing adult tickets at 36.00 
Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : Y

Enter your option: 3
Enter the number of tickets: 1
You are purchasing senior tickets at 32.50 
Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : Y

Enter your option: 1
Enter the number of tickets: 1
You are purchasing child tickets at 18.00 
Do you wish to continue?  (Y/N) : N

Total Price           : $122.50
```